# Would a public upload folder be a security issue?

Tags: apache, security, server

On my site, I have an ability for users to upload a file into the server and be able to view all uploaded files in a directory called "public uploads" where users can view all files that's been uploaded by other users. It's the Apache directory page where it says "Index of /uploads". It's sort of a file sharing hub where people can download and share other people's files.

Would there be any security issues with this? 
Can a user, say, upload a malicious PHP script, and execute it from the client side?

How can I resolve these issues, should they exist?

Comment: “Can a user, say, upload a malicious PHP script, and execute it from the client side?” – Did you try it?

Comment: Need anymore help with this? If so I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, it all depends on server, PHP and Apache configuration.

See [OWASP's Unrestricted File Upload vulnerability page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload) for some of the risks:

> - The impact of this vulnerability is high, supposed code can be
>     executed in the server context or on the client. The likelihood of a
>     detection for the attacker is high. The prevalence is common. As a
>     result the severity of this type of vulnerability is High.
> - The web
>     server can be compromised by uploading and executing a web-shell which
>     can run commands, browse system files, browse local resources, attack
>     other servers, and exploit the local vulnerabilities, and so forth.
>     This may also result in a defacement.
> - An attacker might be able to put
>     a phishing page into the website.
> - An attacker might be able to put
>     stored XSS into the website.
> - This vulnerability can make the website
>     vulnerable to some other types of attacks such as XSS.
> - Picture uploads
>     may trigger vulnerabilities in broken picture libraries on a client
>     (libtiff, IE had problems in the past) if the picture is published
>     1:1.
> - Script code or other code may be embedded in the uploaded file,
>     which gets executed if the picture is published 1:1.
> - Local
>     vulnerabilities of real-time monitoring tools, such as an antivirus,
>     can be exploited.
> - A malicious file (Unix shell script, windows virus,
>     reverse shell) can be uploaded on the server in order to execute code
>     by an administrator or webmaster later -- on the server or on a client
>     of the admin or webmaster.
> - The web server might be used as a server in
>     order to host of malware, illegal software, porn, and other objects.

[See my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28063570/413180) for some general guidelines on making file uploads safe.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing users to upload files to a public folder does not pose a risk for your server. They cannot run these files on your server.

It does pose a risk for users that download any of these files. These files may contain a virus or malware. Opening any of these files is a high security risk for your users. Not sure you're doing them a favor offering such a feature.