# What files to restrict in a PHP upload script?

Tags: php, security, file-upload, upload, restrict

I have written a simple upload script in PHP to allow users to upload files. In their upload folder I have placed a .htaccess file that has one line:

```
Deny From All
```

Obviously, I will restrict users from uploading `.htaccess` and `php.ini`. I don't want to restrict more files than necessary, and the .`htaccess` files should protect against malicious php files or JavaScript. What other files do I need to restrict to be 100% sure that I am not leaving any vulnerabilities in my upload script?

Comment: i will depend on what you actually do with the uploaded files.And what protection do you think ` .htaccess` is providing?

Comment: I will be doing all sorts of things with the files and there will be a lot of things I need to consider for that. I will deal with the processing of uploaded files later. For now, will this line `$file = "zzz".$file;` and my `.htaccess` file provide 100% protection?

Comment: i dont see that provides any protection - but then again it depends exactly what you do with the files

Comment: I am not doing anything with the files. I will deal with that later. For now I just want to make sure my upload script is safe. Surely, the files will be safe when the users have no way to access the files.

Comment: you cant just deal with it latter. what you do with them is fundamental to how to secure them.

Comment: OK thank you. I thought so. I was just worried that there might be similar vulnerabilities to a malicious user overwriting my `.htaccess`. I think I've solved my question with this `$file = "zzz".$file;`.

Comment: Surely, I can do it later. Until I have written code to display uploaded images, what harm can the uploaded image do, even if it does contain malicious code?

Comment: well that's the first time you haven even mentioned images - as far as we know people could be uploading *.php files to run, for images, make sure they are images by check the mime info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Would a public upload folder be a security issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441871/would-a-public-upload-folder-be-a-security-issue)

Comment: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/10/how-securely-allow-users-upload-files see: Ineffective Strategies for Securing File Upload Scripts

Answer (score 1):

I think .php would be a good start. In addition to that remember to check the filetype with `mime_content_type`.

Comment: Why would I need to restrict `.php` files? Won't my `.htaccess` protect against malicious scripts in them?

Comment: @DanBray, I am just answering your question "what files to restrict in php upload?". But what is more important for you is to check the content of the file, so that no one uploads a php file with .jpg extension and execute it on your server. For example, a shell that will give access to all your files.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to do a simple rename.

```
$file = "zzz".$file;
```

The "zzz" can later be removed before processing the files. Now I don't even need to restrict `.htaccess` or `php.ini` from being uploaded.

Comment: Don't forget to take a look at this presentation about executable images before you feel too safe, brother https://www.defcon.org/images/defcon-15/dc15-presentations/dc-15-schrenk.pdf

Comment: I will look at that in detail before I allow any image uploads to be displayed. I am sure there is a lot to consider to safely process uploads, but just for my upload script itself, I think this should be safe `$file = "zzz".$file;`.